# Wordpress feed redirect to the some URL

Tags: wordpress, rss

There is a problem when I hit the url http://somesite.com/rss it redirect to the url http://feeds.feedburner.com/sitename.
can any one tell why this is happerning.

Answer (score 1):

RSS is basicly the channel, not page or post in wp world. Or it could be redictered via 301 code...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont want it to redirect. It stays on the same url and show the rss data.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to provide the actual url where you are seeing this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try deactivating some plugin. You probably installed feedburner plugin. Thanks

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Go to feedburner.com login using your credentials and deactivate the service, you are done.
If you have installed feedburner plugin in wordpress deactivate it.

You are done.